# Using Multiple Where Statements

Tags: sas

I'm attempting to filter out records that contain specific words within a string for the `REASON_FOR_VISIT` variable. I then want to use the remaining records to compute the median values for the variable `total_ed_los` and `arrive_to_dr_sees`.

I have the following code but I'm afraid that it's not filtering out the strings I would like it to. Is this an instance I need to use `PROC SQL` or are there other options?

Thanks!

```
data FT_Post;
set WORK.FT_May;
Where checkin_time between '12:00't and '20:00't;
Where REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psyc%';
Where REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psy eval%';
Where REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psych%';
Where REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicid%';
Where REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicid%'; 
run; 

proc means data=FT_Post median;
class checkin_date;
var  total_ed_los arrive_to_dr_sees;
run;
```

Comment: Why not just add an AND/OR between the conditions?

Comment: @Reeza so you're suggesting something like this `where checkin_time between '12:00't and '20:00't and REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psyc%' and REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psy eval%' AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psych%' And REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicid%' And REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicid%';`

Comment: Assuming that meets your needs. You may need OR or something else between the reason_for_visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple 'vanilla' where clauses in a datastep you will see the following in the log:

> NOTE: WHERE clause has been replaced.

To avoid this behaviour, you can use `where also`:

```
data FT_Post;
set WORK.FT_May;
Where checkin_time between '12:00't and '20:00't;
Where also REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psyc%';
Where also REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psy eval%';
Where also REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psych%';
Where also REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicid%';
Where also REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicid%'; 
run;
```

You will now see:

> NOTE: WHERE clause has been augmented.

Comment: Note that you can use `where also` for all of them.  Which can make some code generation easier (in a macro for example) since you don't need to know which one is the first one.