# Can any answer if we have multiple where condition in SAS progrm, then why last where output shows?

Tags: sas, where-clause

Can any answer if we have multiple **where** condition in SAS program, then why last where output shows always?

How it executed logically?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide some example code with data provided as `datalines` or one of the `sashelp` library data sets that others can run that shows what you are saying. Also explain what you mean by "shows always" are you referring to the log? If yes, then also show the part of the log you are referring to.

Comment: There is a better version of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658433/using-multiple-where-statements

Answer (score 2):

The SAS log explains pretty well what is happening.

```
18   data test;
19    set sashelp.class ;
20    where age=12;
21    where sex='M';
NOTE: WHERE clause has been replaced.
22   run;

NOTE: There were 10 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
      WHERE sex='M';
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 10 observations and 5 variables.
```

If you want to add to filtering criteria then use the `where also` command (also known as `where and`).

```
23   data test;
24    set sashelp.class ;
25    where age=12;
26    where also sex='M';
NOTE: WHERE clause has been augmented.
27   run;

NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
      WHERE (age=12) and (sex='M');
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 3 observations and 5 variables.
```